# Magento 1.7 Observer Module

Tags: php, magento, observers

I have been struggling to get my observer module to work.  I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 and everything appears to be correct for the XML.  No errors, but I don't believe it's firing.  I want it to do three things on the event sale_order_save_after as follows:

If Order status is 'Complete' then do the following:

1) Change custom attribute 'location' to 'SOLD'

2) Change visibility from Catalog/Search to Catalog.

3) Remove all products on order from all of their assigned categories to just one new category (which is ID:80)

And finally save/refresh cache.  My php code is not complete, but I would at least like it to fire.  The first step and second step should work, not sure how to handle changing the categories programmatically.

Here is what I have for code:

App/Code/Local/Pinnacle/Autoarchive/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pinnacle_Autoarchive>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Pinnacle_Autoarchive>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
                <Pinnacle_Autoarchive>
                    <class>Pinnacle_Autoarchive_Model</class>
                </Pinnacle_Autoarchive>
        </models>
    </global>        
            <adminhtml>
                 <events>
                     <sales_order_save_after>
                         <observers>
                             <pinnacle_autoarchive>
                                <type>model</type>
                                <class>pinnacle_autoarchive/observer</class>
                                <method>salesOrderSaveAfter</method>
                             </pinnacle_autoarchive>
                         </observers>
                     </sales_order_save_after>
                </events>
       </adminhtml>
</config>
```

App/Code/Local/Pinnacle/Autoarchive/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
/*
 * Auto Archive all products on last order when status is complete
 */
class Pinnacle_Autoarchive_Model_Observer
{

public function salesOrderSaveAfter($observer)

{
   $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $orderStatus = $order->getStatus();


        if ($orderStatus == 'complete') {
                $items = $order->getAllItems();
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    $productsToUpdate[] = $item->getProductId();
                }
                $theAttributeToUpdate = 'location';
                $theAttributeValue = 'SOLD';
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($productsToUpdate, array($theAttributeToUpdate => $theAttributeValue), 0);
                }

        if ($orderStatus == 'complete') {
                $items = $order->getAllItems();
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    $productsToUpdate[] = $item->getProductId();
                }
                $theAttributeToUpdate = 'visibility';
                $theAttributeValue = 'Catalog';
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($productsToUpdate, array($theAttributeToUpdate => $theAttributeValue), 0);
                }

        //if ($orderStatus == 'complete') {
                //$items = $order->getAllItems();
                //foreach ($items as $item) {
                //    $productsToUpdate[] = $item->getProductId();
                //}

                //Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->$productsToUpdate->setCategoryIds(array(80));
                //}//            

}
?>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated, as I cannot seem to get this to work out.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: please try to call class in xml file as  <class>Pinnacle_Autoarchive_Model_Observer</class>

Comment: Drop a `var_dump(__METHOD__);exit;` at the start of your observer to test if it's firing or not.

Comment: Alan - where exactly should I add the var_dump?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this link

http://snipplr.com/view/56959/

And also make your etc/modules/config.xml

or you can compare your existing code with this one you can sure find your solution to add your code at after save method when any order place.

hope this will sure help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `config.xml` is the problem.  You have the observer defined inside of `adminhtml` instead of `global`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pinnacle_Autoarchive>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Pinnacle_Autoarchive>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
                <Pinnacle_Autoarchive>
                    <class>Pinnacle_Autoarchive_Model</class>
                </Pinnacle_Autoarchive>
        </models>

        <events>
             <sales_order_save_after>
                   <observers>
                        <pinnacle_autoarchive>
                           <type>model</type>
                           <class>Pinnacle_Autoarchive_Model_Observer</class>
                           <method>salesOrderSaveAfter</method>
                         </pinnacle_autoarchive>
                    </observers>
              </sales_order_save_after>
         </events>

    </global>        
</config>
```

Comment: Sean - I changed the xml to the above as suggested.  Not getting any errors, but not getting the attribute changing either after order status changes to 'complete'  Any ideas on how to check if it's firing or not? Is the code for changing the attribute correct? Any advice would be great - thanks again for your help.

Comment: In your Observer, put `die('test');` in `public function salesOrderSaveAfter($observer) {`.  When the Observer fires it should stop and you will see "test" on the screen.

Comment: Sean - it seems it is not firing.  Any ideas?  And is there any other way to start my php script other than using the observer for the order status 'complete' ?

Comment: Did you try @keyur-shah suggestion?  I edited my answer to reflect his suggested class.

Comment: Sean - That seemed to get it firing, but on the order page it locks up with a blank white screen. I don't see anything in the log file. Any ideas?

Comment: Look for `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in your `index.php` file and uncomment it.  It will show you the exact error you're having when you get to that white screen.